# Comparison Cloud in wordcloud2 package in R

Tags: r, wordcloud2

Is there a way to make a comparison cloud with the `wordcloud2` package in R. I want a wordcloud that is colored by a categorical variable in the dataset and a legend to be created on the wordcloud. This is an example in the original `wordcloud` package which is done using `comparison.cloud()`:

[image]

Comment: That doesn't seem to be an option. You can look at the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corpustools/corpustools.pdf) and their [vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/wordcloud2/vignettes/wordcloud.html) but the word "comparison" does not come up anywhere.

Comment: Yeah, I figured it was not an option but thought maybe I was missing something. Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

In `wordcloud2` you can use the `color` argument to set a vector with the colors. In my dataset I had a column with the words, another with the frequencies and a third one with the respective color-categories.

This is what my code looked like:

> wordcloud2(df, color = df$colors, size = .6, shape = "circle")